# Sencha Touch2: List and detail panel inside Container with layout vbox

Tags: listview, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi i am new to sencha touch2, in a container i am showing a list on left side and detail view on right side. and now want to show the detail layout with cliked item text of the list. 
here is my View.

```
   Ext.define('TestApp.view.VboxEx',{
    extend:'Ext.Container',
    xtype:'vbox_ex',
    requires:['Ext.dataview.List'],
    config:{
        layout:{
          type:'hbox'
        },
        items:[
        {
            docked:'top',
            xtype:'titlebar',
            title:'Vertical box'
         },

            {
                xtype: 'list',
                id: 'mylist',
                flex:1,
                docked: 'left',
                style:'background-color:lightgreen',
                store: 'Training_data',
                pinHeaders: false,
                width: 331,
                itemTpl: [
                    '{name}'
                ]

             },

            {
                xtype:'component', 
                flex:3,
                id: 'myDetail',
                html:'Flex3',
                style:'background-color:lightyellow'
            }

        ]

    }


});
```

Here is my controller:

```
Ext.define('TestApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config:{
        refs: {
            listView: '#mylist'
             },


        control: {
            'listView': {
                 itemtap: 'onItemTap'
            }


        }
    },

    onItemTap: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
        console.log('Item was tapped on the Data View');
        var record = view.getStore().getAt(index);
        var selectdValue = record.get('name');
        console.log('Selceted Item index: '+index);
        console.log('Selceted Item value: '+selectdValue);
        // here how can i change the text(selected value) in my detail panel ? 
    },

    onLaunch: function () {
        console.log('onLaunch');
    }
});
```

How can i achieve this? can anyone please help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add new refs in controller -

```
refs:{
 listView: '#mylist',
 detailsPanel : '#myDetail'
}
```

This will give you a readymade `getter` provided by sencha touch with following -

```
var panel =  this.getDetailsPanel();
```

Then change your `onItemTap` method to following --

```
onItemTap: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
        console.log('Item was tapped on the Data View');      
        var selectdValue = record.get('name');
        console.log('Selceted Item index: '+index);
        console.log('Selceted Item value: '+selectdValue);
        // here how can i change the text(selected value) in my detail panel ? 

       this.getDetailsPanel().setData(record.getData());
    },
```

This will set data to your `myDetails` component.

Look carefully, I've removed one line from this method that is -

```
var record = view.getStore().getAt(index);
```

you already have everything you need in `record` argument of `onItemTap` method. So you probably don't need to get it from store again.

*Most important*  thing, for this to work is, you need to add `template` to your component. like following

```
        {
            xtype:'component',
            flex:3,
            id: 'myDetail',
            style:'background-color:lightyellow',
            tpl: "<h2>{name}</h2>"
        }
```

Here `{name}` will display value passed from controller.

This will definitely work. Try it. And as a side note, instead of using `component` to show details use **panel** . Component is more generic. So you could use panel instead.

Comment: have you added refs in controller and component is one as defined above ? Refs is referring to component having id `myDetail`.

Comment: Its working thanks. and how can i add seperate panel(i mean to say different screen) instead of text on list item tap ?